# Products in a category

Tags: category-theory

Let $C$ be a category and let A,B,C be three objects of $C$..Should the products
 $Π$(B,C),  $Π$(A,B,C), $Π$(Α,$Π$(B,C)) exist, is it true in general that $Π$(A,B,C) and $Π$(Α,$Π$(B,C)) are isomorphic?? Or does the statement holds for certain types of categories, e.g. Additive ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, these must be isomorphic. You can prove this by the Yoneda lemma. Let $X = \prod (A,B,C)$ and $Y = \prod (A, \prod(B,C))$. Then by universal property, we have natural isomorphisms of sets$\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}$

$$\Hom(Z,X) \cong \Hom(Z,A) \times \Hom(Z,B) \times \Hom(Z,C)\\ \cong \Hom(Z,A) \times \Hom(Z,\prod(B,C)) \cong \Hom(Z,Y)$$

(these are natural in $Z$). This shows that $\Hom({-},X) \cong \Hom({-},Y)$, so $X \cong Y$.

Comment: Thank you, that is a good use of the Yoneda lemma!!

Comment: I get the isomorphism of X and Y via the natural transformation constructed in Yoneda's Lemma proof, am I right??

Comment: $\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}$That may be correct, depending on what you mean. The Yoneda lemma gives you a natural isomorphism $\Hom(\Hom({-},Q),F) \to F(Q)$ (natural in the presheaf $F$ and the object $Q$). An isomorphism $\Hom({-},X) \to \Hom({-},Y)$ therefore determines a map $X \to Y$, its inverse determines a map $Y \to X$, and naturality tells you that these maps $X \to Y$ and $Y \to X$ are inverse to each other!

Comment: I am not familiar with sheaf and presheaf settings, but regarding the second part thats exactly what I meant. I needed this to prove some equivalent conditions of an additive functor. More specific I used the above product isomorphy to prove that a functor (covariant) $F$ preserves finite products or coproducts iff $F$ is additive

Comment: A presheaf on a category $\mathsf{C}$ is nothing more than a functor $\mathsf{C}^{\text{op}} \to \mathsf{Set}$ (i.e. a contravariant functor from $\mathsf{C}$ to the category of sets)! A morphism of presheaves is just a natural transformation, and the category of presheaves so defined is the codomain of the Yoneda embedding.